# Adjusting dropdown in ExtJS combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I need such combobox, that's it dropdown's width ant that one of input are different **and** dropdown is adjusted to the right edge of the input.

First part is easy - juts set `matchFieldWidth`  to false and assign `listConfig.width = something`. But what is the easiest way to perform the adjustment? Here is a picture which illustrates the question.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll be the first, but will not gain a reputation - all we should do - is just set `pickerAlign` to `tr-br`.